# Showing that an electric field is uniform

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, capacitance, gauss-law

This question might be a bit strange.  Two charged plates will have a uniform electric field between them.  Is there a relatively simple way to show that the electric field between them is constant?  I'm thinking of something along the lines of using Coulomb's law to show that the force on a given charge anywhere in between the plates will be constant.

Big thanks to anybody that might have a useful answer to this question.

Comment: Gauss' law using Cartesian geometry shows the flux is independent of the size of the Gaussian box.

Answer (score 1):

Well, recall how you derived the electric field for an infinite charged plate. You started by admitting that the plate has a charge surface density $\sigma$. Then, you used a Gaussian surface, in this case, a cylinder with surface $A$. Then the total charge inside the Gaussian surface is simply $\sigma A$. The electric flux is simply $\Phi=2EA$, because there is electric flux going out of the Gaussian surface by either side of the cylinder. Moreover, the flux is also equal to the charge over $\varepsilon_0$ (Gauss's law), which is $\Phi=2EA=\sigma A$. Then the electric field over the plate is:

$$
E=\frac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon_0}.
$$

Now, apply this for the case of two infinite oppositely charged parallel conducting plates. Because each plate contributes to the electric field, and also because the electric field is linear we can add the to contribution and we then have:

$$
E=\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0}.
$$

Comment: In order to use Gauss' law to find the value of the field you have to assume that the field is uniform. You cannot use it to show that is uniform. The uniformity comes from symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hand-waving way to visualize your question.  Imagine you have a single point change in space.  It's easy to visualize the electric flux lines radiating out equally in all direction, and getting weaker with distance due to the inverse-square law.

Now imagine a large number of such point charges uniformly distributed on an infinite (or at least very large) x,y plane.  Now choose a point **p** that is some distance z above this plane.  You can determine the total electric flux vector (magnitude and direction of the flux) at **p** by summing the individual flux vector contributions from all the points on the plane.

What you will find is that the components of flux vectors in the x and y directions will all sum to zero, leaving only a component in the z direction.  Furthermore, the magnitude of this resultant flux vector will be the same at all locations and all distances from the x,y plane.  So you are left with a uniform electric field perpendicular to the plane.